# Package installation freezes at "building initial module for 4.15.0-33-generic

Tags: apt, 18.04

Somehow installation of any package is freezing on Ubuntu 18.04. It does not depend on the package which I want to install.

The freeze is on the same line:

```
Building initial module for 4.15.0-33-generic
```

Some of the lower lines from the output of `sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib` are:

```
[...]

snd-hda-codec.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.15.0-34-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 0.201808050301~ubuntu18.04.1 completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new oem-audio-hda-daily-0.201808050301~ubuntu18.04.1 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building for 4.15.0-33-generic and 4.15.0-34-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.15.0-33-generic
```

I tried to run the installation over night, but it just stays at the same point.

Does anyone know any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after couple days of research and trying different stuff out I found a solution.

There is a hidden password input field. So one has to type the sudo user password couple of times. Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/8r3zov/stuck_at_building_initial_module/e0z7oli